# UItableviewcell glitch

Tags: ios, uitableview

So sometimes upon returning to my main menu for my game I am greeted by something quite extraordinary. As you can see from the picture I have replicated cells outside the UIView Table. Now at first I thought it was a graphics corruption that was based on memory issues, Then I discovered you could interact with them, they are valid cells...not ghost images and they respond to code, So I then did a little search and though that my table was stuck in editing mode or something so I call setediting:NO everywhere I could. And it haunts me still.

Does anyone even have the first idea what could be causing this? It does not happen all the time but it only ever seems to happen...IF it does when I am popping back to this screen from another view on top of it. I also can't replicate it consistently so it's hard to fix and know what is causing it.

Please keep in mind I might be doing something or not doing something I have not mentioned so don't forget to ask everything you may think relevant and I will be happy to inform you.

[image: Table Cell Glitch]
EDIT:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[CurrentGamesInfo sharedCurrentGamesInfo] _currentGames] count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _indexPath = indexPath;
     NSLog(@"%i",_indexPath.row);
    [_indexPath retain];

    [[CurrentGamesInfo sharedCurrentGamesInfo] SetCurrentGameWithIndex:[_indexPath row]];

    UIView *tempView = [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] contentView] viewWithTag:200];

    if([[[(UIButton*)[tempView viewWithTag:CELL_BUTTONTEXT_ID] titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"Waiting"])
    {
        return;
    }

    if( ![[CurrentGamesInfo sharedCurrentGamesInfo] _selectedGame].isGameReady )
    {
        [_PopUp OptionsMessage:@"Game Not Ready" withTitle:@"Hold Your Horsies" hideBackButton:YES];
        return;
    }

    NSString *gameID = [[[CurrentGamesInfo sharedCurrentGamesInfo] _selectedGame] GetGameID];

    NSLog(@"%i",[[[CurrentGamesInfo sharedCurrentGamesInfo] _selectedGame] GetTurnNumber].intValue);

    NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[AppDelegate applicationDocumentDirectory:gameID]];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];

    PhotoImage *photoImg = [[PhotoImage alloc]init];
    [photoImg set_imageToSend:image];
    [[[CurrentGamesInfo sharedCurrentGamesInfo] _selectedGame] SetImageToSend:photoImg];
    [photoImg release];

    UIImageView * imgView = (UIImageView*)[[[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] contentView]viewWithTag:300] viewWithTag:301];
    [[[CurrentGamesInfo sharedCurrentGamesInfo]_selectedGame]setOpponentProfilePic:imgView.image];

    [self TempCurrentGameFunction];
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

WARNING: HEFTY FUNCTION INCOMING

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    GameInfo *gameThisRow = [[[CurrentGamesInfo sharedCurrentGamesInfo]_currentGames] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

    NSLog(@"row : %i",indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"current game count : %i",[[[CurrentGamesInfo sharedCurrentGamesInfo] _currentGames]count]);

    NSString *gameType = @"";

    UIButton *gameStatusButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, -5, 90, 70)];

    Boolean isYourTurn = [[gameThisRow GetPlayerRole] intValue] ? YES : NO;

    NSString *gameStateString = @"Your Move";
    [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [cell setTag:ACTIVE_GAME_CELL];

    if(!isYourTurn)
    {
        //_activeGameCount--;
        gameStateString = @"Waiting";
        [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [cell setTag:INACTIVE_GAME_CELL];
    }

    [gameStatusButton setTitle:gameStateString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[gameStatusButton titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Fredoka One" size:10]];
    [gameStatusButton setTag:CELL_BUTTONTEXT_ID];

    if( indexPath.row  < [[[CurrentGamesInfo sharedCurrentGamesInfo] _currentGames]count])
    {
        switch ([gameThisRow gameType]) 
        {
            case 0:
                gameType = @"Open Game";
                [gameStatusButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonB_blue.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                break;

            case 1:
            {
                gameType = @"Challenge Game";
                [gameStatusButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonB_orange.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            }

                break;

            case 2:
            {
                gameType = @"Battle Game";
                [gameStatusButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonB_pink.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",[[gameThisRow GetFaceBookData]objectForKey:@"name"]);

    NSString *name = [[gameThisRow GetFaceBookData]objectForKey:@"name"];

    UIView *labelView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 10, 100, 50)];
    [labelView setTag:200];

    [labelView addSubview:gameStatusButton];
    [gameStatusButton release];

    [labelView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UILabel *labelName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 100, 20)];

    NSString *text = name;

    NSArray *nameArray = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    NSString *nameWithInitials;

    nameWithInitials = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[nameArray objectAtIndex:0]];

    for( int i = 1; i < nameArray.count; ++i )
    {
        NSString *temp = [nameArray objectAtIndex:i];
        nameWithInitials = [nameWithInitials stringByAppendingFormat:@" %C.",[temp characterAtIndex:0]];
    }

    text = nameWithInitials;

    int maxSize = 20;
    int minSize = 8;
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Fredoka One"size:maxSize];

    /* Time to calculate the needed font size.
     This for loop starts at the largest font size, and decreases by two point sizes (i=i-2)
     Until it either hits a size that will fit or hits the minimum size we want to allow (i > 10) */
    for(int i = maxSize; i > minSize; i=i-2)
    {
        // Set the new font size.
        font = [font fontWithSize:i];
        // You can log the size you're trying: NSLog(@"Trying size: %u", i);

        /* This step is important: We make a constraint box 
         using only the fixed WIDTH of the UILabel. The height will
         be checked later. */ 
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake([labelName frame].size.width, MAXFLOAT);

        // This step checks how tall the label would be with the desired font.
        CGSize labelSize = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        /* Here is where you use the height requirement!
         Set the value in the if statement to the height of your UILabel
         If the label fits into your required height, it will break the loop
         and use that font size. */
        if(labelSize.height <= [labelName bounds].size.height)
            break;
    }
    // You can see what size the function is using by outputting: NSLog(@"Best size is: %u", i);

    // Set the UILabel's font to the newly adjusted font.
    [labelName setFont:font];

    // Put the text into the UILabel outlet variable.
    [labelName setText:text];

    [labelName setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [labelName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [labelName setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [labelView addSubview:labelName];
    [labelName release];

    UILabel *labelSubtitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 100, 50)];

    [labelSubtitle setText:gameType];
    [labelSubtitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Fredoka One" size:10]];
    [labelSubtitle setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [labelSubtitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [labelSubtitle setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];

    [labelView addSubview:labelSubtitle];
    [labelSubtitle release];

    [[cell contentView] addSubview:labelView];

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=200&height=200",[[gameThisRow GetFaceBookData]objectForKey:@"id"] ]; 

    UIImageView *pictureImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    [pictureImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-Small.png"]success:^(UIImage *image)
     {
         pictureImage.image = [image imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];

     } failure:^(NSError *error) 
     {
         [pictureImage setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-Small.png" ]imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(50, 50)]];
         NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
     }];

    NSLog(@"%@",[pictureImage image]);

    pictureImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    [pictureImage setFrame:CGRectMake(pictureImage.frame.origin.x+20, 37 - 25, 50, 50)];

    UIImageView *pictureFrameView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile_frame.png"]];
    CGRect temp = pictureImage.frame;
    //hand & hard coded, i feel so ashamed and sullied
    temp.origin.x -= 12;
    temp.origin.y -= 9;
    temp.size.width = 70;
    temp.size.height = 73;
    [pictureFrameView setFrame:temp];

    UIView *pictureView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];

    [pictureView addSubview:pictureFrameView];
    [pictureView addSubview:pictureImage];
    [pictureImage setTag:301];
    [pictureFrameView release];
    [pictureImage release];

    [[cell contentView] addSubview:pictureView];
    [pictureView setTag:300];
    [pictureView release];



    //custom stuff start
    UIImage *rowBackground;
    //UIImage *selectionBackground;
    NSInteger sectionRows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:[indexPath section]];
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    if (row == 0 && row == sectionRows - 1)
    {
        rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_bottom.png"];
        //selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topAndBottomRowSelected.png"];
    }
    else if (row == 0)
    {
        rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_top.png"];
        //selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"topRowSelected.png"];
    }
    else if (row == sectionRows - 1)
    {
        rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_bottom.png"];
        //selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomRowSelected.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"table_mid.png"];
        //selectionBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"middleRowSelected.png"];
    }
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:rowBackground];
    [cell setBackgroundView:imageView];
    [imageView release];
    //((UIImageView *)cell.selectedBackgroundView).image = selectionBackground;
    //custom stuff end

    __block CGRect newPos = inviteFriendsParentView.frame;
    CGRect tempCurrentGameSubMenuFrame = currentGameSubMenu.frame;
    tempCurrentGameSubMenuFrame.size.height = [friendsTable rowHeight] * [friendsTable numberOfRowsInSection:0] + 10;
    currentGameSubMenu.frame = tempCurrentGameSubMenuFrame;
    float bottomofFrameYPos =  currentGameSubMenu.frame.size.height;
    newPos.origin.y += bottomofFrameYPos;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I will be tough to diagnose anything without any code. Are you using different cell identifiers in your various tableviews? If not, you should try to make sure that you do so. It feels like you have some dequeued cells, combined with some bug around the `numberOfRowsInSection`. I'd start with `NSLog` of the `UITableViewDataSource` # of sections and number of rows. I assume you're just using a data source and that you're not manually populating the tableviews? All of this is conjecture, as it's impossible to diagnose from one screen snapshot.

Comment: Yes, please provide us with some code. As stated above, you may need to set unique identifiers for each cell.

Comment: Which parts of the tableViewCell delegate methods would you like to see? i warn you cellForRowAtIndexPath is quite hefty. I'll add bits and pieces but if you need to see that method i will add it